# Powerapps Collection Limited To 5 Entries

Tags: ms-office, powerapps

I'm trying to solve an issue with Microsoft PowerApps where you are limited to storing only 5 values in a collection, I have been looking around for a while now to find a solution.

What I am essentially trying to do is create an offline issue logger from a tablet, where users will sync their devices to a database to retrieve all existing entries. They will then go offline to a customer site and take pictures and log issues offline to then sync when they get back to the office.

With this issue persisting, I cannot import more than 5 issues from the database and I cannot log more than 5 issues to then upload to the database.

I have gone through the documentation a few times now trying to find anything stating whether the storage is limited or not. I haven't been successful.

Tutorials such as : https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/tutorials/show-images-text-gallery-sort-filter/ show that they are adding 5 products to work with, but that is the only mention of data in a collection.

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue? Or could anyone suggest a way around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The Collection view under File > Collections only shows 5 items in the table.

If you create a dropdown of the data, all the values are saved offline.

Answer (score 0):

By default a collection can hold up to 500 entries, if you need more entries than this you can create code to expand the limit. If you go to File > Collections, again it only shows 5 items as an example of the data. This is replicated in the tutorials and can lead you to believe that 5 is the maximum number of items you can store.